# SKPaymentQueue finishTransactions not removing transaction from queue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

The `updatedTransactions:` delegate callback is firing with old transactions from several days ago.  I tried calling `finishTransactions` on them, but when I launch the app, the same exact transactions are still there (checked the `transactionIdentifier`) over and over again.

I'm unable to make any new purchases. When making a new purchase, one of these old transactions will get returned in the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state, but because it was already previously successful, I get an error from Apple: *"This In-App Purchase has already been bought. It will be restored for free. [Environment: Sandbox]"*

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJAdh.jpg)

How can I properly remove the transaction from the transaction queue?

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions {

    // Getting called with old, already finished transactions

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                // ...
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // ...
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // validate receipt first
                // then finish transaction
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                // ...
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I confirmed that `finishTransactions` is not removing them from the queue.

```
NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *transactions = [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
NSLog(@"BEFORE transactions = %@", transactions);
for (SKPaymentTransaction *txn in transactions) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:txn];
}
transactions = [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
NSLog(@"AFTER transactions = %@", transactions);
```

Outputs:

```
BEFORE transactions = (
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8b10>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8c60>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8c40>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8c20>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8b00>"
)
AFTER transactions = (
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8b10>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8c60>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8c40>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8c20>",
    "<SKPaymentTransaction: 0x2802c8b00>"
)
```

**EDIT #2:**

I found on the Apple dev forums that this is affecting some others in the past 48 hours.. I believe this to be an issue on Apple's side.

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678105
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678235

**EDIT #3:**

We reached out to Apple via our partnerships team and was able to confirm that Apple's services were indeed down during this time but that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

`finishTransaction:` method should do what you want to achieve. However, the way how you test the behaviour is not correct since there is another delegate method from StoreKit `paymentQueue:removedTransactions:` to get removed transactions.

It is possible that there is small amount of delay between `finishTransaction:` and the actual removal. Therefore, `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions]` can still return the transactions if you call it directly after `finishTransaction:`

I suggest you to validate removal of transactions with the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to mark all `purchased`, `restored`, and `failed` transactions as `finished`, not only the `purchased` ones.

To start again with an empty transaction queue, I would recommend you to add the following line to the initialize code in your store component or wherever you handle purchases:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions.forEach({ SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0) })
```

This will mark all currently open transactions as finished and allow you to start over with an empty transaction queue.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post to include the call to finishTransactions for the `failed` and `restored` state.  Unfortunately `finishTransactions` is still not removing them from the queue.  I logged the `defaultQueue` before and after.

Comment: Did you try what @seref bulbul suggested?

Comment: We reached out to Apple via our partnerships team and was able to confirm that Apple's services were indeed down during this time and that the issue has been resolved.  Thanks for following up!

Answer (score -1):

You can call this line of code in the

```
extension StoreKitManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    
          SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions.forEach({
          SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)})
    }
    }
```